# Is there a way for webdriver to detect automatically that the browser url has changed?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have framework built out in selenium. I am trying to add additional functionalities to it. For this, I need to execute some piece of code each time the url changes - maybe because of button/link click or navigate() or get().
Now i know about WebDriverEventListener which helps me to override behavior of get() and navigate() but i do not have a straight way to identify url change on button or link click.
Is something this this available that informs the code that the url has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Python using `WebdriverWait` and `expected_conditions`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

url = 'https://example/before'
changed_url = 'https://example/after'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# wait up to 10 secs for the url to change or else `TimeOutException` is raised.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_changes(changed_url))
```